Correspondence theorem and Quotient ring isomorphism
The following is taken from Abstract Algebra A Comprehensive Introduction by: Lawerence and Zorzitto.
Background
The ideal in a commutative ring $R$ generated by eleements $a_1,\dots, a_n$ is denoted by the wedge bracket notation:
$$\langle a_1,\dots, a_n \rangle$$
and sometiems the more informative noatation
$$Ra_1+Ra_2\dots +Ra_n.$$
Proposition 4.32 (Euclidean division with polynomials).  If $R$ is a commutative ring and $g$ is a non-zero polynomial in $R[X]$ such that its leading coefficient is a unit of $R$, then for eveyr $f$ in $R[X]$ there exist unique polynomials $q,r$ in $R[X]$ so that
$$f=gq+r\quad\text{and}\quad \text{deg }r<\text{deg }g\text{ or }r=0.$$
In particular, if $R$ is a field, then the above holds for all non-zero $g$.
Propositiion 4.49 (Correspondence theorem).: Let $\phi: R\to A$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. (Here $R,A$ need not be commutative.)  Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the family of ideals of $R$ containing $\text{ker }\phi$. and $\mathcal{L}$ the family of ideals of $A$.
(1) If $J \in\mathcal{J}$, then $\phi(J) \in\mathcal{L}$
(2) If $L \in\mathcal{L}$, then $\phi^{-1}(L) \in \mathcal{J}$
(3) If $J \in\mathcal{J}$, then $\phi^{-1}(\phi(J))=J.$
(4) If $ L\in\mathcal{L}$, then $\phi(\phi^{-1}(L))=L.$
(5) The mapping $\mathcal{J}\to \mathcal{L}$ defined by $J\mapsto \phi(J)$ is a bijection whose inverse is the mapping $\mathcal{L}\to \mathcal{J}$ defined by $L\mapsto \phi^{-1}(L)$
(6) If $J\in \mathcal{J}$, then $R/J\cong A/\phi(J) $
An Illustration of the Correspondence Theorem

The  isomorphism in item 6 of the correspondence theorem can be useful in detectin the nature of some quotient rings.  Here is a scenerario which could occur.
$\quad$ Say $R$ is a commutative ring and $a,b\in R$.  What can Proposition 4.49 reveal about the quotient ring $R/\langle a,b\rangle$?  Well, the canonical projection $\phi:  R\to R/\langle b\rangle$ is a surjective homomorphism, and its kernel is the principal ideal $\langle b\rangle$.  The ideal $\langle a,b \rangle$ contains $\langle b\rangle$.  By a simple verification the image $\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)$ is the ideal $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ inside $R/\langle b\rangle$.  Since $\phi(b)=0$ the image $\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)$ is the principal ideal $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$.  According to the correspondence theorem
$$R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle).$$
The right side is a succession of quotients of two principal ideals, which more readily be deciphered.
$\quad$ For example, let us describe the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2+1,X-2 \rangle$.  Start with the substitution map $\phi:\Bbb{Z}[X]\to \Bbb{Z}$ given by $f\mapsto f(2).$  This is a surjection and its kernel is the ideal $\langle X-2\rangle$.  Indeed, $\langle X-2\rangle\subset \text{ker }\phi$ because $X-2$ has a root at $2$.  On the other hand $f\in \text{ker }\phi$.  Since $X-2$ is monic, Proposition 4.32 gives a polynomials $q,r$ in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f=(X-2)q+r$ and $r$ is constant.  From $f(2)=0$ it follows that $r=0,$ and thus $f\in \langle X-2\rangle$.
$\quad$ The correspondence theorem gives a bijection between the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ containing $\langle X-2\rangle$ and the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$.  Now $\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle$ contains $\langle X-2\rangle$.  By item 6 of the correspondence theorem
$$\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}/\phi(\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle).$$
In $\Bbb{Z}$ the ideal
$$\phi(\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle)=\langle \phi(X^2+1),\phi(X-2)\rangle=\langle 2^2+1,2-2\rangle=\langle 5\rangle$$
Thus
$$\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle=\Bbb{Z}_5.$$
The original quotient is isomorphic to the finite field $\Bbb{Z}_5$.
$\quad$ Let us see what happens if we carry out the process in a different order.  Take the substitution map $\psi:\Bbb{Z}[X]\to\Bbb{Z}[i]$ given by $f\mapsto f(i)$.  This is a surjective homomorphism and its kernel is $\langle X^2+1 \rangle$.  Indeed, $\langle X^2+1 \rangle\in \text{ker }\psi$ because $i$ is a root of $X^2+1$.  On the other hand let $f\in \text{ker }\psi$.  Since $X^2+1$ is monic, Euclidean division gives polynomials $q,r$ in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f=(X^2+1)q+r$ and $r$ is of the form $a+bX$ for some $a,b$ in $\Bbb{Z}$.  Since $f(2)=0$ we get $r(2)=a+bi=0.$ By the nature of complex numbers $a=b=0$, and thus $r=0$.  Having seen that $f=(X^2+1)q$ it follows that $\text{ker }\psi=\langle X^2+1 \rangle$.  By item 6 of the correspondence theorem
$$\Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}[i]/\psi(\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle) =\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle \psi(X^2+1),\psi(X-2)\rangle=\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle i-2\rangle.$$
Putting all of this together we come up with the less than obvious discovery that
$$\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle i-2\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}_5.$$

Questions
I have some questisons about the above exposition on the illusration of the correspondence theorem.  I often see post such as: Describe the ring structure quotient ring $Z[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,2)$. and isomorphism $\mathbb{C} [X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$.  I often wonder there is some slight missing justifications especially in the first reference post in the sense if we are given a quotient ring with its ideal that is finitely generated, then there such problem.  Anyways, onto my questions (a) and (b) below:

(a) By a simple verification the image $\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)$ is the ideal $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ inside $R/\langle b\rangle$.  Since $\phi(b)=0$ the image $\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)$ is the principal ideal $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$.  According to the correspondence theorem
$$R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle).$$

and

(b) $\phi(\langle X^2 +1, X-2\rangle)=\langle \phi(X^2+1),\phi(X-2)\rangle=\langle 2^2+1,2-2\rangle=\langle 5\rangle$

For (a) I understand that "$\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)$ is the ideal $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$" is due to Proposition 4.49 (1) since $\langle a,b \rangle\in \mathcal{J}$ and $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle\in \mathcal{L}$.  But which is inside $R/\langle b\rangle$? $\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)$ or $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$? And how?
When it says "Since $\phi(b)=0$ the image $\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)$ is the principal ideal $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$", I am guessing "$\phi(b)=0$" is part of the or is the kernel of some evalulation map.  And $\langle \phi(a)\rangle=\{\langle\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)\rangle\mid \langle a,b\rangle\in \mathcal{J}\}$, but how do $\phi(b)=0$ relate to the principal ideal $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$?  Lastly how does the correspondence thorem give rise to the following isomorphism:  $R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle)$?  I understand that there should be some map going from $R/\langle b\rangle\to R/\langle a,b\rangle$ with $\langle a\rangle$ being the kernel of the said map?  But how do: By a simple verification the image $\phi(\langle a,b \rangle)$ is the ideal $\langle \phi(a),\phi(b)\rangle$ inside $R/\langle b\rangle$.  Since $\phi(b)=0$ the image $\phi(\langle a,b\rangle)$ is the principal ideal $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$. along with the correspondence theorem give rise to the isomorphism:  $R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle)$?  I think the map should be $r+\langle b\rangle\mapsto r+\langle a,b\rangle$.
For (b) what justifies the step $\langle 2^2+1,2-2\rangle=\langle 5\rangle$?  I mean which paprt of the correspondence theorem allows one to simply plug in the numbers $2$ into $\langle X^2+1,X-2\rangle$.
Thank you in advance

(b) You probably overlooked that $\phi$ is defined as the homomorphism that plugs the number 2 into polynomials.

@Stefan I don't understand.  Can you please elaborate how can $phi$ be defined as such?  I mean, i have never seen such an homormorphism can be defined where the whole purpose is to plug in numbers into a polynomials in an ideal.

The definition is given in the text you quoted: "Start with the substitution map $\phi:\Bbb{Z}[X]\to \Bbb{Z}$ given by $f\mapsto f(2).$". You can verify yourself that this does indeed define a ring homomorphism. This is absolutely fundamental for working with polynomials and I'd be surprised if it wasn't covered in detail earlier in the book.

@Stefan yes, yes.  Okay, I see what you mean.  That is on me for not making the connection.  Can I ask you about in (1) about $R/\langle a,b\rangle\cong (R/\langle b\rangle)/\langle a\rangle).$.  I don't understand how is the ocrrespondence theorem is used here.

(6) is used. By $\langle a\rangle$ they mean $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$, probably a deliberate abuse of notation to make the result look nicer.

@Stefan the map $R/\langle b\rangle\to R/\langle a,b\rangle$ given by $r+\langle b\rangle\mapsto r+\langle a,b\rangle$ with kernel $\langle \phi(a)\rangle$ is correct?

Doesn't look wrong, but it's not clear what your purpose is, since you have to use (6), not prove it. This might be my last comment.

@Stefan ah okay okay, thank you so much for all of your help.
